# Access data from promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I thought I somewhat understood promises but I guess not.  I am trying to access the data from the request that my promise made.

```
function getData(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   window.api.getTimesByCompanyAndLocation(1, 5, function(error, data, response){
    if(error){
     reject({error, response});
    }
    else{
     resolve(response);
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Then to access the data:

```
getData().then((result) => {
 console.log(result);
});
```

When I check the network I can clearly see the request has been made and data is in the response. But my simple console.log has no data.

Thanks

Comment: Looks all alright, are you sure the `getTimesByCompanyAndLocation` is indeed getting a response as the third argument? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Please show `api.getTimesByCompanyAndLocation`. Thanks.

Comment: No idea about that API but maybe try `resolve(data);` instead?

Comment: You have console logged the resolve path, yes? And logged the value of data and response, yes?  What do they tell you?

Comment: Did you make sure by debugging that the `getTimesByCompanyAndLocation` callback is called with the argument values that you expect?